# php - if use array as function argument how fill function array parameter

Tags: php, arrays, function

If I use array as function argument like this:

```
  function test($arg = array('name'=>'','position'=>'')){
     echo $arg['name'];
  }
```

how when use this function fill array parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call the function like:

```
test(array('name'=>'username', 'position'=>'director'));
```

What you have there `function test($arg = array('name','position'))` is the default param value.

You can read more about it here: http://php.net/manual/ro/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 0):

Call it with an array:

```
$name = "Fred";
$position = "President";
test(array('name' => $name, 'position' => $position));
```